# No element in the source document matches /configuration/system.web/authorization/

Tags: web-config, authorization, roles, web.config-transform

I have the next issue when transforming my Web.Config:

> No element in the source document matches '/configuration/system.web/authorization/allow[@roles='WhateverGroupNameRenamedForProd']'

Here my
**Web.Config:**

```
 <system.web>
<compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" debug="true" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<authorization>
  <allow roles="WhateverGroupName" />
  <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

And the **Web.Production.Config:**

```
<system.web>
<compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
<authorization>
  <allow roles="WhateverGroupNameRenamedForProd" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(roles)"/>
</authorization>
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 7):

For the ones already interested, I found and fixed the problem: It was basically on the SetAttributes:

My old code:

```
<allow roles="WhateverGroupNameRenamedForProd" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(roles)"/>
```

Should be replaced by:

```
<allow roles="WhateverGroupNameRenamedForProd" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(roles)"/>
```

Then you have so specify the attribute name on the **SetAttributes**, in my case it was "roles".

Comment: You have to understand what `xdt:Locator=Match(roles)` means and so why it didn't work :  *Find the element in the source file with specified value for roles (i.e. **WhateverGroupNameRenamedForProd**)*, then do the transform (`SetAttributes`). Since the `<allow` element in your source file had a role value of **WhatevetGroupName**, it did not match.