# Warning : No element in the source document matches '/configuration/connectionStrings/add[@name='MyDB']'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have asp.net project that I need to publish to Azure

Here is My webconfig file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!-- For more information on using Web.config transformation visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301874 -->

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyDB"
       connectionString="Server=tcp:vchasnotestserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=vchasnotestdb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=***;Password=********;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

When I deploy to azure, I get this warning in output

> 2>C:\Users\nemes\Source\Repos\vchasnocrm-new\vchasnocrm\Web.Release.config(7,8): Warning : No element in the source document matches '/configuration/connectionStrings/add[@name='MyDB']'

How I can fix this?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40342950/no-element-in-the-source-document-matches-configuration-system-web-authorizatio

Comment: But its for auth, I have error for db@RuiJarimba

Comment: it's a similar problem, read his answer.

Comment: Try replacing `xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"` with `xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(name)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your Web.config transformation under `Web.Release.config`, the transformation code is valid. For the warning message you provided:

> Warning : No element in the source document matches '/configuration/connectionStrings/add[@name='MyDB']'

Per my test, it means that there does not exist a `connectionString` named `MyDB` under your `Web.config` file. So you could ignore this warning message. For overriding your connectionString before deploying to azure, you need to make sure there has a connectionString named `MyDB`, or you need to adjust the connectionString name under your `Web.Release.config` file.

Moreover, if you use Azure Web Apps to host your web application, you could leverage Application settings in Azure App Service to override your existing settings at run-time. For your requirement, you could log into Azure Portal and choose your web app, click "SETTINGS > Application settings" and add your connection string with the same name defined under your `Web.config` file. Details you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure).

Comment: Thank's. Yeah, my db is working great. But message looks confusing

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may have the same issue I had, make sure that the Web.config file in your project is set to "Content", otherwise the file will not be published, and there will be no "source" to compare to.